# IndexOutOfRangeException in zlib compression of iTextSharp

Tags: itext, zlib

I found a pretty annoying and serious problem in iTextSharp's zlib implementation. Very hard to reproduce because it depends on the actual data going into the PDF but in some circumstances, the following exception occurs:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.util.zlib.Tree.d_code(Int32 dist)
at System.util.zlib.Deflate.compress_block(Int16[] ltree, Int16[] dtree)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `System.util.zlib.Tree.cs`, there is obviously no range check, only an assumption of things never going wrong. Adding the following `(byte)` cast seems to be a solution:

```
internal static int d_code(int dist){
  return ((dist) < 256 ? _dist_code[dist] : _dist_code[256+(byte)((dist)>>7)]);
}
```